# What can I do if my quick app was rejected and the error message indicates that an error has occurred?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

When I submit my quick app for review in AppGallery Connect,my quick app was rejected and the error message indicates that an error has occurred? What does the message means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is generally displayed because some minor errors exist in your quick app code.

A common error is that an element is bound to an event callback function, but the function has not been defined. You need to install Huawei Quick App IDE and Huawei Quick App Loader and debug your app.